# Graphics drivers only work once

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

So I’ve installed Ubuntu for the first time in my life. There seems to be a problem with the graphics drivers every time I run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390` for example. And I reboot everything looks perfect. But then when I reboot everything is back to blurry like it’s when I first installed Ubuntu. Now the things that I tried were:

- deleting Ubuntu entirely and reinstalling it again
- deleting all Nvidia drivers and (purge it?)
- tried to install the drivers from the .run file from the Nvidia website but kept getting the same error message something like cc package not installed and script has an error something like that. I have a new RTX 2080 card from MSI so maybe it’s because of that but I find that highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the solution, I didn't disable secure boot which prevented the drivers from working(?). Anyways I disabled Windows 10 support in the bios form MSI and now the drivers are working.